# Factorial combination list in python

Tags: python, combinations, factorial

Suppose I have a list of data like this `[['a', 'a', 'b'], ['a', 'a', 'b','b']]`

I want to output a list of all permutation for `a = 1 or 2, b = 3 or 4`

For the case of `['a', 'a', 'b']`, to output:

```
[1,1,3]
[2,1,3]
[1,2,3]
[2,2,3]
[1,1,4]
[2,1,4]
[1,2,4]
[2,2,4]
```

How do I do this? Thank you for helping

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Check out the `collections` module.

Comment: so far I tried itertools permutations and tried to do a recursion but it didn't work. Did a simple loop too but it couldn't scale to different size list

a = [1,2]
b = [3,4]
for i in range(0,len(a)) :
   for j in range(0,len(a)) :
       for k in range(0,len(b)) :
           for l in range(0,len(b)) :
               print(a[i],a[j],b[k],b[l])

Comment: can you show us how your simple loop not working?

Comment: the simple loop works well, but it only works for when the number of elements in the list is fixed. If i want to change the number of element in the list from 4 to 10, it would not work

Answer (score 2):

If you structure your input slightly differently, the below works:

```
from itertools import product

values = {
    'a': [1, 2],
    'b': [3, 4]
}

case = ['a', 'a', 'b']

coms = product(*[values[c] for c in case])

for c in coms:

    print(list(c))
```

Prints:

```
[1, 1, 3]
[1, 1, 4]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 4]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 1, 4]
[2, 2, 3]
[2, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find all permutations of a list with [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
>> import itertools
>> list(itertools.permutations(['a', 'a', 'b'])
[('a', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'a')]
```

In your case you want to test all combinations of values between `a` and `b`, so for your first case:

```
import itertools

for a in range(1, 3):     # a is 1 or 2
    for b in range(3, 5): # b is 3 or 4
        # Construct your list for this combination of values of a and b
        l = [a, a, b]

        # Find all permutations and print them
        print(list(itertools.permutations(l))
```

Your second case would be the same, but you would need to adjust the `l` variable accordingly.

You can do this for a list of lists, as in your original request, by creating the list automatically from a previously specified list:

```
all_lists = [['a', 'a', 'b'], ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b']]

for this_list in all_lists:
    for a in range(1, 3):     # a is 1 or 2
        for b in range(3, 5): # b is 3 or 4
            # Construct your list for this combination of values of a and b
            l = [a if x == 'a' else b if x == 'b' else x for x in this_list]
            print('Permutations for ' + str(l))
            print(list(itertools.permutations(l)))
            print('-----------')
```

If you run the above code you'll realise there are a bunch of duplicate permutations, because there are duplicate values in the list (`[1, 1, 3, 3]` permutates to itself three times: switching only the first 1 with the second 1, switching only the first 3 with the second 3, and switching both the 1s and the 3s). If you want to get rid of duplicate values in your result, you can use `set(itertools.permutations(l))` instead of `list(itertools.permutations(l))`, since `set()` does not allow for duplicate values.

Comment: @mylee No problem. I've updated the answer to include a way of not having to duplicate the whole permutation structure for your case.